# using flex components in pure actionscript without any mxml

Tags: actionscript, mxml

my Main.as extends flash.display.Sprite, I want to use a ComboBox component in the as, without any mxml, how to implement it? 
I read this [Possible to use Flex Framework/Components without using MXML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141288/possible-to-use-flex-framework-components-without-using-mxml), its main as extends spark.components.Application, but still need a mxml file. Its main idea is to rewrite the Application component, and reuse it in mxml file. That is not what I want.
 I uses Flex SDK 4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use Flex components without having your application extend the Flex Application class. The components always require the Flex container.

Either you turn your application into a Flex one - which is possible without using MXML - or you should consider using a pure AS implementation of a ComboBox: [GUI Framework for flash (as3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265476/gui-framework-for-flash-as3)