# Objective-C, Methods for animating gui

Tags: objective-c, user-interface, animation

I've created many types of interfaces using the Cocoa API — some of them using [documented basic animation techniques](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAnimation_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and others simply by experimenting (such as placing an animated .gif inside an NSImage class) — which had somewhat catastrophic consequences. The question I have is what is the correct or the most effective way to create an animated and dynamic GUI so that it runs optimally and properly?

The closest example I can think of that would use a similar type of animation would be something one might see done in [flash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/265476/gui-framework-for-flash-as3) on any number of interactive websites or interfaces. I'm sure flash can be used in a Cocoa app, although if there is a way to achieve a similar result without re-inventing the wheel, or having to use 3rd party SDKs, I would love to get some input. Keep in mind I'm not just thinking of animation for games, iOS, etc. — I'm most interested in an animated GUI for Mac OS X, and making it 'flow' as one might interact in it.

Answer (score 0):

If u wish to add many graphics animations, then go for OpenGLES based xcode project for iOS. That helps u to reduce performance problem. You can render each of the frames in gif as 2D texture.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you take a look at Core Animation. It is Apples framework for hardware accelerated animations for both OS X and iOS. It's built for making animated GUIs.

You can animate the property changes for things like position, opacity, color, transforms etc and also animate gradients with [CAGradientLayer](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAGradientLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html) and animate non-rectagunal shapes using [CAShapeLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/Reference/Reference.html) and a lot of other things.

A good resource to get you started is the [Core Animation Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004627-SW1).